# static arraylist creating infinite instances of itself

Tags: java, arraylist

My understanding is that a static variable will exist to be shared across all instances of the class that the variable resides in.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Game {

    private static final ArrayList<Game> GAMESLIST = new ArrayList<Game>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    private int gameID;
    private int teamScore1;
    private int teamScore2;
    private int temperature;
    private String teamName1;
    private String teamName2;

    public void PlayGame(Team team1, Team team2, int value, String teamNameValue1, String teamNameValue2, Scheduler scheduler){

        temperature = value;
        int maxGoals = 2;
        int iterator;

        if(temperature > 12){
            for(iterator = 0; iterator < temperature; ++iterator){
                ++maxGoals;
                if(maxGoals == 8){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        teamScore1 = rand.nextInt(maxGoals);
        teamScore2 = rand.nextInt(maxGoals);
        teamName1 = teamNameValue1;
        teamName2 = teamNameValue2;

        ++gameID;
        System.out.println(teamScore1);
        System.out.println(teamScore2);

        GAMESLIST.add(this);
        scheduler.PlayGame();
    }

    public void PrintStatistics(){
        int iterator;

        for(iterator = 0; iterator < this.GAMESLIST.size(); ++iterator){
            System.out.println("Game# " +this.GAMESLIST.get(iterator).gameID);
            System.out.println("Team 1: " +this.GAMESLIST.get(iterator).teamName1);
            System.out.println("Team 2: " +this.GAMESLIST.get(iterator).teamName2);

            System.out.println(GAMESLIST.get(iterator).teamScore1);
            System.out.println(GAMESLIST.get(iterator).teamScore2);
            System.out.println("Recorded temperature that day: " + GAMESLIST.get(iterator).temperature);
        }   
    }


public class Scheduler {

    Random rand = new Random();

    private Team[] teams;
    private Team team1, team2;
    private Game game;
    private int temperature;
    private int numberOfColdDays = 0; 

    public Scheduler(){

    }

    public Scheduler(Game gameValue, Team[] teamsValue){
        game = gameValue;    
        teams = teamsValue;
    }

    public void PlayGame(){

        if(IsTooCold() == true){
            System.out.println("Too cold to play!"); 
            ++numberOfColdDays;
            if(numberOfColdDays < 3){
                SoccerLeague.PlayGame(this);
            }
            else{
                SoccerLeague.EndSeason(this);
            }
        }
        else{
            numberOfColdDays = 0;
            TeamPicker(teams);
            game.PlayGame(team1, team2, temperature, team1.teamName, team2.teamName, this);
        }
    }

    public void TeamPicker(Team[] teams){
        int value1;
        int value2;

        value1 = rand.nextInt(3);
        team1 = teams[value1];

        do{
            value2 = rand.nextInt(3);
            team2 = teams[value2];
        }while(value1 == value2);
    }    

    public boolean IsTooCold(){
        boolean tOrF = false;

        System.out.println("Is it too cold to play?");
        this.temperature = rand.nextInt(30);

        if(temperature < 7){
            tOrF = true;
        }   
        return tOrF;
    }

    public void PrintGames(){

    }
}
```

When running the debugger in the IDE, I get an infinite amount of instances of `this` object created inside the `ArrayList` for one instance of type `Game`.

Also, after the specific conditions are met and it's time to print the `ArrayList`, the `for` loop will print at random a single iteration and print a random amount of the instances of that one iteration that was created earlier.

Is my code failing in `Game` class somewhere, in the `PlayGame` method or the `PrintStatistics` method?

Also, note that I have tried removing the `this` keyword entirely from the loop in the `PrintStatistics` method, but I still get the same result.

As always, any help is appreciated.

***EDIT*** As requested, the scheduler class.

Regards, MYLESMAN

Comment: Just a note: Static variables don't belong to any instance but the class. Using `this` which references the current object instance for static variables makes little sense. Use the classname to reference static fields instead: `Game.GAMESLIST` instead of `this.GAMESLIST`

Comment: What's `scheduler`? It's likely you have recursion, but it's impossible to tell without context.

Comment: `PrintStatistics()` should be static as well. Pay attention on information that debugger provides to you `...@123` - this is unique `id` of the object. I am sure, that all your `this.GAMELIST` - is the same object.

Comment: What about the parameter for adding the instance of game to the ArrayList, Oh God Spiders?

Comment: You probably want to move `GAMESLIST.add(this);` to the Game class constructor and not some method of it, because it may be called multiple times or how is your `PlayGame` method called? If you only have once instance of your game class the static List makes no sense at all. Also you can use a simple for each loop in your `PrintStatistics` method, that would simplify your iterator stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have unobvious endless loop.

You have an method Game.PlayGame which adds your game to list and calls scheduler.PlayGame(). However scheduler.PlayGame() calls game.PlayGame() in its turns. It leads to adding game to gamelist many times and may lead to StackOverflowError and OutOfMemoryError.